# Convert a list into accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to convert my list items in an accordion. But, when I use following code, it seems jQuery is being removed and replaced the link (href) even for a list item which doesn't have any children. For Example - list item 2 and 5. Can anyone help me with this?

```js
$(function() {

    var count = 1;
    var lisize = $( "ul > li" ).length;

    $( "ul > li" ).each(function(){

        if (count <= lisize) {
            $( "ul > li:nth-child(" + count + ") > a" ).attr ("href", ".collapse"+count);
            $( "ul > li:nth-child(" + count + ") > a" ).attr ("data-toggle", "collapse");

            $( "ul > li:nth-child(" + count + ") > ul" ).addClass( "collapse collapse"+count );

            count++;    
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#1">List Item 1</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">List Item 2</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#3">List Item 3</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>P</li>
            <li>Q</li>
            <li>R</li>
            <li>S</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#4">List Item 4</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>K</li>
            <li>L</li>
            <li>M</li>
            <li>N</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#5">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @emineminems I want to achieve an accordion which will display children of list item 1,3,4 on clicking on the <a> of those list items. But, it should take me to the actual mentioned link for the list items that don't have children. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @emineminems yes, correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added `main` as id to the main ul wrapper so that you can limit where you iterate from. Also changed the conditional statement to `$(this).children("ul").children("li").length > 0` so that the system checks if the ul has children - only then will it add the accordion classes

```js
$(function() {

  var count = 1;
  var lisize = $("#main > li").length;

  $("#main > li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).children("ul").children("li").length > 0) {
      $(this).children("a").attr("href", ".collapse" + count);
      $(this).children("a").attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
      $(this).children("ul").addClass("collapse collapse" + count);

      count++;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul id="main">
  <li>
    <a href="#1">List Item 1</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#2">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#3">List Item 3</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li>P</li>
      <li>Q</li>
      <li>R</li>
      <li>S</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#4">List Item 4</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li>K</li>
      <li>L</li>
      <li>M</li>
      <li>N</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#5">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue:  limit selection to all li having an ul child

```
$('ul > li:has(> ul)')
```

Second issue: [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) has two parameters, so you don't need the count variable because you can use the first parameter.

Last note: you may use directly [.attr( attributes )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes) in order to set two attributes for the anchor instead of calling .attr() method twice.

The snippet:

```js
$('ul > li:has(> ul)').each(function (idx, ele) {
  $(ele).children('a').attr({"href": ".collapse" + idx, "data-toggle": "collapse"});
  $(ele).children('ul').addClass("collapse collapse" + idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#1">List Item 1</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">List Item 2</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#3">List Item 3</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>P</li>
            <li>Q</li>
            <li>R</li>
            <li>S</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#4">List Item 4</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>K</li>
            <li>L</li>
            <li>M</li>
            <li>N</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#5">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```